# Does RazorGenerator support Include and Raw functions?

Tags: razor, razorgenerator

I am following the instructions here:
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html, to use precompiled razor templates. But one my generated .cs files has build errors.

> The name 'Include' does not exist in the current context.
>
> The name 'Raw' does not exist in the current context.

I'm not very familiar with all things Razor. I'm using MVC5. I am using templates in a library project, so I tried moving them to an existing MVC project, but I still get the same build errors. I'm not using any `@* Generator: ... *@` header on the template with the build errors. (Using any of the headers results in more build errors.)

So, does RazorGenerator support the @Include and @Raw functions, or is there a better way to do this that is supported by RazorGenerator?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the build errors by changing @Include to @Html.Partial and @Raw to @Html.Raw in the .cshtml file.

Apparently, Include is not supported, but Partial, Raw and some other @Html functions are supported when generating in MvcView mode. No @Html functions are supported when generating in Template mode.